# Visual Studio 2008 asking for restart

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl

I am trying to load the data from tally to sql server database. I have created ssis package i have mapped everthing and i can look at data preview as well. But when i click on execute package it's asking me to restart visual studio. I am running it on windows 7 ultimate. Any idea. [image]

Comment: Something in your package is causing the SSIS host process, DtsDebugHost.exe, to fail, hard. What is your package doing? What are your sources? Do you have custom scripts in the package, etc?

Comment: No just i am trying to load the data from tally to sql server. No costume scripting in it.....

Comment: I can able to look at preview and when click on execute it asking me to restart Visual Studio